# How to restart previous activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android app, I have an activity that displays profile information. Then it opens a new activity to make changes to the activity. After you save changes, it closes the edit activity from the edit activity, then goes back to the profile displaying activity, there I need to restart this activity to refresh the data.

Is there a way I can restart the activity that opened the current activity?

Comment: Why not just trigger an update when coming back from the activity in `onActivityResult()`?

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways you can achieve what you want:

1. Start the profile activity by calling `startActivityForResult()` and refresh your data in `onActivityResult()`
2. `Finish()` the activity when start the profile activity and then override `onBackPress()` in the profile activity to start the previous activity and then call `finish()`.
3. Override `onBackPress()` in the profile activity to start the previous activity with the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and refresh your data in `onNewIntent()`

Comment: hmm, same thing happened with me sometimes too.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Android Activity Result Pattern** that communticates parent and child activities:

In your profile activity (parent):

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    startActivityForResult(
      new Intent(this, NameActivity.class), 
      1); // 1 to identify caller activity.
  }


  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      updateProfile();
    }
  }
```

In your editor activity (child):

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    setResult(
      RESULT_OK);

    finish();
  }
```

Comment: This actually did the work i needed.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to "restart" Activity A.

You can call `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` to start your new Activity, and then receive extras via the `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` call.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Alternatively, look into the [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method, which is called every time your screen becomes visible.  Assuming you persisted some state in Activity B (e.g. a SharedPreference or a database record), in onResume() you can refresh Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

Activity Display;

Activity Modification;

When you startActivity M in your Activity D,don't D.finish();
then, when you M.finish(),you don't need "restart" Activity D,because it is already there.

You have two choices to "refresh the data":

1.startActivityForResult as they said.I won't explain any more.

2.make a cache.
save data in some static variables or sqlite or even sharedPreference.Then in onResume() of Activity D,get those data and show them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: If A is calling B and when B ends you need to update A, then in A launch B with `startActivityForResult()`. When B returns, the method `onActivityResult()` of A will be called. In this method (of A) you can test, if necessary, that some stored values are changed. At this point you do something like:

```
finish();
startActivity(intent); //start the activity A
```